# Load GTK DLLs from relative path

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have a GTK+/C program that requires GTK+ DLLs to be in the same folder as the executable to run . i would like to place all these DLLs to a folder named (bin) and tell my program from where it could load these DLLs .

- Programming language : C
- DLLs : GTK+ windows binaries
- IDE : Code::Blocks
- OS : Windows 7, x_86

Answer (score 0):

If you put your executable and gtk libs in `bin` it should work fine.

Comment: I'm using windows (as i mentioned) not linux .

Comment: I am aware. GLib based applications should be using [g-win32-get-package-installation-directory-of-module()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Windows-Compatibility-Functions.html#g-win32-get-package-installation-directory-of-module) which handles being placed in `bin` for you.